# Can I obtain an accurate count of log messages matching some a given filter using a logs-based metric?

Tags: google-cloud-monitoring

We have a Google Cloud Function that is logging structured log records like so:

```json
{
  "insertId": "000000-49d4463c-3689-4f57-ae30-99026b9dab27",
  "jsonPayload": {
    "type": "eventreceived",
    "events": 1,
    "metric": "real-time-event-processor",
    "organisationId": 1,
    "message": "Received event: 'profileUpdate'",
    "channelId": "Unknown",
    "eventType": "profileUpdate"
  },
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_function",
    "labels": {
      "region": "europe-west2",
      "function_name": "myfunc",
      "project_id": "myproject"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2022-01-10T14:03:21.891Z",
  "severity": "INFO",
  "labels": {
    "execution_id": "XXX"
  },
  "logName": "projects/myproject/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions",
  "trace": "projects/myproject/traces/fa4ee7b25dc68324fa7dfe421b99ad5d",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2022-01-10T14:03:31.746860973Z"
}
```

and we have built a logs-based metric on top of such log messages. Here is the terraform code that defines that logs-based metric:

````hcl
resource "google_logging_metric" "real_time_event_processing_events_received_per_eventtype" {
  # To view the logs that contribute to this metric run the following (changing project & prefix accordingly)
  # ```
  # gcloud logging read --project=myproject 'resource.type = "cloud_function"
  # resource.labels.function_name = "prod-dp-realtime-event-processing"
  # jsonPayload.metric="real-time-event-processor"' --format='table[box](jsonPayload.eventType,jsonPayload.eventversion,jsonPayload.channelId,jsonPayload.organisationId,timestamp)'
  # ```
  # Here's some sample output:
  # ┌─────────────────┬────────────┬─────────────────┬──────────────────────────┐
  # │    EVENT_TYPE   │ CHANNEL_ID │ ORGANISATION_ID │        TIMESTAMP         │
  # ├─────────────────┼────────────┼─────────────────┼──────────────────────────┤
  # │ consentUpdate   │ 116        │ 1               │ 2021-10-21T13:49:08.870Z │
  # │ consentCreation │ 116        │ 1               │ 2021-10-21T13:49:07.207Z │
  # │ consentCreation │ 116        │ 1               │ 2021-10-21T13:48:55.004Z │
  # │ consentUpdate   │ 116        │ 1               │ 2021-10-21T13:48:29.956Z │
  # │ consentCreation │ 116        │ 1               │ 2021-10-21T13:48:28.815Z │
  # │ accountCreation │ 116        │ 1               │ 2021-10-21T13:28:55.111Z │
  # └─────────────────┴────────────┴─────────────────┴──────────────────────────┘
  name        = "real-time-event-processing-events-received-per-eventtype"
  project     = var.project_id
  description = "Real time event processing - events received per EventType"
  filter      = "resource.type=cloud_function AND resource.labels.function_name=${google_cloudfunctions_function.realtime_event_processing.name} AND jsonPayload.metric=real-time-event-processor"
  metric_descriptor {
    metric_kind  = "DELTA"
    value_type   = "INT64"
    display_name = "events received per EventType"
    labels {
      key         = "eventType"
      value_type  = "STRING"
      description = "Event Type"
    }
    labels {
      key         = "channelId"
      value_type  = "STRING"
      description = "channelId"
    }
    labels {
      key         = "organisationId"
      value_type  = "STRING"
      description = "organisationId"
    }
  }
  label_extractors = {
    eventType      = "EXTRACT(jsonPayload.eventType)"
    channelId      = "EXTRACT(jsonPayload.channelId)"
    organisationId = "EXTRACT(jsonPayload.organisationId)"
  }
}
````

From this logs-based metric I can build a nice chart on a monitoring dashboard showing the curve of eventType over time:
[image]

However what I now want to do is get an accurate answer to the question *How many log messages did I receive with eventType='consentCreation' in a given time frame?*

I've tried putting a scorecard that uses my logs-based metric onto my dashboard to try an answer that question. This is how I've configured the Scorecard:

[image]

and this is what it produces:

[image]

This isn't what I want. I'm not interested in number of messages per second, I want to know the actual number of messages in the time period that has been specified.

I'm wondering if perhaps that isn't the sort of question that logs-based metrics are conducive to answering and/or I am using them wrongly.

If someone can tell me if its possible to answer my question using logs-based metrics and if so, how, I would be very grateful.

Comment: maybe this video would help a little https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YiwT1cxpRDQ

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Running into same need.

Comment: I think I came to the conclusion that this isn’t what logs based metrics are for. I’m hoping Log Analytics (https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/log-analytics) will help solve problems like these.

Comment: @jamiet ah that does look like a relevant solution, I'll check it out. Thanks for following up.